# opengl shader Coordinate Systems

Tags: c++, opengl, math, optimization, shader

I learn OpenGL on  page : https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems
In example they use 3 matrix (Model, View, Projection) and push all to the shader program. But can calculator MVPmat = Projection * View * Model on CPU and push one time to the shader.

1. Use 3 matrix:

   - +Use GPU.
   - +Clean.
   - -Need calculator MVPmat for all pixel.
   - -Use 16 or 32 bit calculator.
2. Use MVPmat = Projection * View * Model on CPU.

   - +One time for each model.
   - +Use 64 bit calculator.
   - -Use CPU.
   - -Not clean.

What is best way ? I can't found answer on GG or may be I am stupid.

P/S Sorry for my English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "clean" vs "not clean". I'm also not sure why exactly you think that computing the Model-View-Projection matrix on the CPU means that this must be done using 64-Bit precision. There should hardly ever be a need for 64-Bit floating-point arithmetic when it comes to graphics-related things. Actually, there should hardly be a need for more than single-precision floating-point in general. Unless, for example, you're doing some scientific computing where you really need that precision…

To answer your question: If using a combined Model-View-Projection matrix is sufficient for what you want to do, then using a combined matrix would seem to be the best solution. You only have to compute the combined matrix once. You only have to upload a single matrix to the GPU instead of three. You only have to fetch one matrix in your shader instead of three. You only have to do one matrix-vector multiplication in the shader instead of three…

Comment: 1. "clean" vs. "not clean" is my own convention "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);" is the beauty of mathematics.
2. Model-View-Projection matrix is best but why some tut use 3 matrix when they teach that can use combining matrices. I will ask author to get answer.
Thanks for help.

Comment: @TKNgu: The reason for using 3 matrices is, that sometimes the results of intermediary multiplication steps are required for some graphics related calculations. For example you normally do all light related calculations before multiplying Projection but after multiplying Model-View.